# cocos2d & TexturePacker: initWithSpriteFrame consuming 16 Mb of memory for a small file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to understand why allocating 5 small `CCSprite` assets via `initWithSpriteFrame` is consuming 16Mb of memory in my application. These 5 small sprites are each a mere `24Kb` in .png format, but then packed into a `pvr.ccz` file via [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). Here are my settings:

[image]

The entire size of the `pvr.czz` file is `2.5 Mb`. Each of the 5 small sprites are `66x66` px (@2x resolution). To match with these settings, I invoke the following in my cocos2d initialization, precaching the sprite sheets on startup:

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

for(NSString *fnSheet in kGlobalSpriteSheets) {
  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:fnSheet];
}
```

Then I call `addOrb` to create the assets, which essentially invokes `CCSprite initWithSpriteFrame` like this:

```
- (id)initWithAsset:(NSString*)assetName {
  CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:assetName];
  return [self initWithSpriteFrame:frame];
}
```

Using profiler, we can see that the `addOrb` function is consuming 16Mb of memory:

[image]

**note** the call stack shows 14 invocations of the `addOrb` function, which is true, but there are only a total of 5 different assets which may be loaded by this function.

The first thing that jumps out at me is that the Profiler seems to indicate that the PVR texture is not being allocated until `initWithSpriteFrame` is called, despite my attempts to preload it (?)

By the time my app startup is complete, my allocated memory is at `225Mb`. This is on the high end, and I'm looking for any ways to pare this down.

---

Edit: After the "precaching", `[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo]` gives me this:

```
2014-08-21 10:24:29.060 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: "cc_fps_images"   rc=5    id=2    512 x 64    @ 16 bpp => 64 KB
```

2014-08-21 10:24:29.060 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo: 1 textures, for 64 KB (0.06 MB)

And after the sprites are allocated:

```
2014-08-21 10:24:29.060 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: "cc_fps_images"   rc=5    id=2    512 x 64    @ 16 bpp => 64 KB
2014-08-21 10:24:29.060 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo: 1 textures, for 64 KB (0.06 MB)
2014-08-21 10:25:15.805 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: "fonts/cinzel_18.png" rc=33   id=5    512 x 256   @ 32 bpp => 512 KB
2014-08-21 10:25:15.806 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: "menu.pvr.ccz"    rc=7    id=6    2048 x 2048 @ 32 bpp => 16384 KB
2014-08-21 10:25:15.806 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: "cc_fps_images"   rc=5    id=2    512 x 64    @ 16 bpp => 64 KB
2014-08-21 10:25:15.806 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: "backgrounds/space.png"   rc=3    id=4    2048 x 1536 @ 32 bpp => 12288 KB
2014-08-21 10:25:15.806 Aftermath[46067:1115151] cocos2d: CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo: 4 textures, for 29248 KB (28.56 MB)
```

So, it looks like the precaching isn't actually loading the files, but regardless: the thing that jumps out is that the `menu.pvr.ccz` (which contains the sprites in question) is consuming `16Mb` of memory despite its `2.5Mb` filesize. I guess this is just a necessary evil? I am aware that file size != memory consumption.

Comment: What's the image's resolution?

Comment: Each of the 5 sprites are 66x66px @2x resolution (question updated to reflect this information).

Comment: what does [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo] tell you ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg question updated with this information!

Answer (score 3):

File size does not equal texture memory usage. Consider the calculation here:

```
"menu.pvr.ccz"    rc=7    id=6    2048 x 2048 @ 32 bpp => 16384 KB
```

Obviously menu.pvr.ccz has a size of 2048x2048 and uses 4 bytes (32 bpp) per pixel.

So:

```
2048 x 2048 x 4 = 16777216 Bytes (16 MB)
```

You may want to verify the image size in TexturePacker. Try changing Size Constraint to something other than Power of 2, though I think PVR textures still require POT sized textures. No harm in trying though.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, but now I'm getting some warnings, probably more a question for the texturepacker team but still: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464398/custom-texture-dimensions-using-texturepacker-and-cocos2d

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Stephen's remark, file size is a function of #pixels, bits per pixel, encoding used, and compression used. Memory on the other hand only depends on # of pixels and bits per pixel. A pixel is a pixel is a pixel. A fully transparent 2048x2048 image will still take 16Mb at 8bpp, but could be quite small on disk.

File size and encoding type affect mostly load speed (.pvr is best, by far).

If you are concerned about memory footprint, test (on the lowest capability device you intend to support) to see if you can afford a 'jit' texture load strategy, ie you can load every time small textures (chose .pvr.ccz) without deteriorating the user's experience.