# Custom texture dimensions using TexturePacker and Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

When I switched from `POT` to `any size` in [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker), per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431893/cocos2d-texturepacker-initwithspriteframe-consuming-16-mb-of-memory-for-a-sma/25433855#25433855), Cocos2D starting throwing this warning:

```
cocos2d: WARNING. Current texture size=(1613,2047). Convert it to size=(1614,2047) in order to save memory
cocos2d: WARNING: File: units_black-hd.pvr.ccz
cocos2d: WARNING: For further info visit: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31092
```

I cannot figure out how to explicitly set a texture size in TexturePacker so that it meets these constraints. `POT` fixes it, of course, but it increases the size of each of my sprite sheets by ~1Mb, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: i believe textureoacker has an option that ensures textures are aligned on word/dword boundaries (2/4 bytes).

Comment: Sure enough! It was hidden in an advanced options area. Posting a screenshot below for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Force word aligned` option (hidden in the Advanced Settings of the Layout section) fixes this!

[image]